# Best practice in publishing multiple bots

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

Currently, I am commenting out / uncommenting code to handle the message queues in a chatbot for publishing the code to a test bot and to the production bot in VS. Are there any known best practices in place of this - basically checking if the published code is going to the production or test bot?

Example from the code:

```
// Production queue
// CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("messagehandlingqueue");

// Testing queue
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("testmessagequeue");
```

Edit (Added details on environments):
Test and production environments are both run on Azure. Basically there are 3 bots running: live production, public development testing, and private dev testing. However, emulator is also used for private testing.

Comment: How about moving the differences to configuration?

Comment: It would be better if you could give some details of your environments. Are test and production environments both in Azure, or you use emulator for testing?
[Official document of ASP.Net Core environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0) could also help.

Comment: Test and production environments are both run on Azure. Basically there are 3 bots running: live production, public development testing, and private dev testing. However, emulator is also used for private testing.

Comment: Can you read environment variable to get the queue per environment.

Comment: Yeah, I can read environment variables. Would there be a way to automatically change the environment variable or would it be a matter of manually changing the variable value?